# Unity Mecanim. How to reset animation before disabling a gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, unity3d-mecanim

Unity 2019.3.7f1
..
The artist I'm working with has made some animations for some UI stuff using the mecanim system Animator component.

I fire the animation with

```
Animator.SetTrigger("ParamaterName")
```

The gameobjects with the animator components, which are being animated, can get disabled by some of my scripts.
This can happen while the animation is playing..
So if the animation starts playing, and lets say the animation has made a button get bigger, then the gameobject gets disabled. When the gameobject is re-enabled (the animation is no longer playing) it is still big..
Is there a way to tell the Animator to go back to normal?
I have tried stuff like this in onEnable and OnDisable in a script on the GameObject

```
    Animator.keepAnimatorControllerStateOnDisable = false
    Animator.Play("normalState",0,0f);
    Animator.playbackTime = 0f;
    Animator.Update(0f);
```

This mecannim thing just seems like a black box as to how it works. I'm not familiar with it as I've always just used my own library to animate stuff that I've been using for donkeys years.

EDIT:
This was the solution...

```
private void Start()
{
    Animator.keepAnimatorControllerStateOnDisable = true;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    Animator.Play("normalState",0,0f);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your [keepAnimatorControllerStateOnDisable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-keepAnimatorControllerStateOnDisable.html) isn't set to true. Instead, you should set to false to clear the current state of the Animator controller

```
Animator.keepAnimatorControllerStateOnDisable = false
```

This way whenever you disable an object with an Animator, the Animator states and all its parameters go back to default.

---

### Update

From your comments was able to understand the default is to have the button bigger. So, it's actually the other way around (set it to true, instead of false).

As you mention, write the following code

```
private void Start()
{
    Animator.keepAnimatorControllerStateOnDisable = true;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    Animator.Play("normalState",0,0f);
}
```

Comment: Cheers but that did not work unfortunately... I tried by putting that line in Start() on the GameObjects in question.

Comment: This means the default is have the button bigger. Try using true instead of false.

Comment: Ok if I do that + also call Animator.Play("normalState",0,0f); on Enable / Disable its ok (without calling that it plays the remainder of the animation when re-enabled) Thanks!